# Switch an array sort from descending order to ascending order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So my program has a function in which I read the numbers from a text file into an array and then sort them in ascending order.  However, instead of sorting in ascending order my code sorts in descending order.  What do I need to change here in order to get my code to work the way I need it to?

```
void displaySortedNums(string fileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fileName + ".txt");
    int numbers[50];
    int arraySize = 0;

    if (!inFile.is_open())
        {
            cerr << "\nUnable to open file " << endl << endl;
        }
    if (inFile.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof())
        {
            cout << "\nData file is empty" << endl << endl;
            cout << "File Successfully Read" << endl << endl;
        }
    else
        {
            inFile >> numbers[arraySize];
            while (inFile)
                {
                    arraySize++;
                    inFile >> numbers[arraySize];
                }
            numbers[arraySize] = '\0';
            double temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize + 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < arraySize + (i + 1); j++)
                    if (numbers[j] < numbers[j + 1])
                    {
                        temp = numbers[j];
                        numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                        numbers[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                cout << numbers[i] << endl;

            }
        }

    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Look for where you're comparing elements and switch the operator? Also why aren't you using `std::sort`?

Comment: Maybe should `if (numbers[j] < numbers[j + 1])` simply become `if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])`?

Comment: `numbers[arraySize] = '\0';` Huh? Where did you get that idea? And why do start out with careful I/O-error checking and then yolo-read an unknown number of values into an array of fixed size?

Comment: @skypjack Thanks it works now

Comment: Well, I'll put the comment in a response, so that you can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
if (numbers[j] < numbers[j + 1])
```

Use the following one instead:

```
if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])
```

The basic idea is quite simple indeed, in the second case you are checking if a number is greater than its successor while in the first one you were checking the opposite.